# Is it possible to do '||' (Javascript) in swift?

Tags: swift

In javascript we can do:

```
var val = null;
var str = val || "ok";
```

Then `str` would be `ok` and not `null` but only if its not null-ish to begin with.

Is there a quick/short way to do this in swift? It's possible to do this:

```
var val:String?

if val == nil {
    val = "OK"
}
```

But if there's a lot of variables to do this to it becomes quite long. Is there a short/er way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the *null coalescing operator*: `??`:

```
var val: String?
val = val ?? "OK"
```